# How do I know with telegram bot if a user has changed telegram profile photo?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

How can I get a picture when the telegram user changes his main photo? Can I get this without cron?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you know [getUserProfilePhotos](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getuserprofilephotos) method.
You can't get notified when users changed their profile photo, so you need to track it, like using `cronjob`.

Comment: thank you, resources are limited so i want without cronjob

Comment: @Sean Could you please help me to fix https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53806530/telegram-bot-api-server-down-when-use-getuserprofilephotos

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getUserProfilePhotos` feature and save the last profile picture in a database. Then by checking the last profile picture in specific time periods (for example every 30 seconds) you can check whether the picture is changed or not. And if it was changed you can notify yourself.

Comment: When there are many users in the list, the server will need a lot of resources. That's why I wanted without kronobe. I asked someone maybe who knows have any events for this?

Comment: I don't think that there's an independent event defined by telegram for this. On the other hand, you can do what I said in a time that is not your server's peak time for example midnight. And as it will just perform a linear search with time complexity of O(n), I don't think that it takes too much time to perform such a search. Note that you don't need to process pictures one by one. You will only need to check the **file ID** of profile pictures and knowing that file ID is unique for each picture, even for millions of users it won't be so slow. I hope this will help you.

Comment: @Naser.Sadeghi Could you please help me for the similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53806530/telegram-bot-api-server-down-when-use-getuserprofilephotos